# How is this movie so close to current epidemic due to COVID-19?

Tags: plot-explanation, production, contagion

I recently watched a movie [Contagion (2011)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1598778/) starring some very high rated actors like Kate Winslet, Gwyneth Paltrow, Matt Damon, Lawrence Fishburne, Jude Law etc.

It seems to have precisely predicted how Coronavirus originated and spread. Some similarities with current situation being,

1. Origin in China.
2. Rumors of being engineered.
3. Similar Symptoms of high fever, dry cough, respiratory issues.
4. Airborne and community spread.

Consequences of those being,

1. Curfew and lockdown of major cities around the world.
2. Canceling of International flights.
3. People working online.
4. Panic buying and subsequent riots.

Precautionary measures taken are,

1. Social distancing.
2. Hand washing frequently.
3. Quarantine and no handshaking.

The sequence is close to current reality. Hence my question is how did they get it so accurate ? Was it inspired from previous outbreaks ?

Comment: How could a movie that is 9 years old be based on a virus outbreak that just occurred?

Comment: @sanpaco: I have updated my question.

Comment: [Outbreak](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114069) was released already 1995

Comment: fun fact: polish title of this movie translate to "Epidemic of fear". I would say this movie is based on human stupidity that show each year with new virus. Sars, H1N1, Ebola, Zika etc. In the 80's you had all those nuclear disaster movies. In 00's all those "wolrd is gonna end on 1000 different ways" movies.

Comment: Sure, Hollywood does these "torn from the headlines" deals all the time prior to it actually happening.  Like the way The China Syndrome was a fictionalized Three Mile Island.  Or the way Fight Club presented a conspiracy theory for 9/11 (blow up the buildings to destroy all the mortgages).

Comment: Really, if you change your question that substantially, just get rid of this thing and ask it anew. What does anyone need with an open question that's at -8 score? However, it is still ultimately a question that's not going to get much different of an answer but "yeah, cool coincidence you noticed" or just answers saying that this is a pretty common scenario (and could as well have been based on the 2003 SARS pandemic). The film certainly isn't precongitive anymore than the human conciousness is.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I am not sure if it's allowed to ask the modified question after deleting it. I might as well get banned for doing so. Hence I resorted to modifying it even though it has -8 votes.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not about Coronavirus.  Neither is "The Eyes Of Darkness" by Dean R Koontz.  Coronavirus is actually a fairly well-known virus that has been around for quite some time.  The CDC defines it as:

> Coronaviruses (CoV) are a large family of viruses that cause illness
>   ranging from the common cold to more severe diseases such as Middle
>   East Respiratory Syndrome (MERS-CoV) and Severe Acute Respiratory
>   Syndrome (SARS-CoV). A novel coronavirus (nCoV) is a new strain that
>   has not been previously identified in humans.
>
> Coronaviruses are zoonotic, meaning they are transmitted between
>   animals and people.  Detailed investigations found that SARS-CoV was
>   transmitted from civet cats to humans and MERS-CoV from dromedary
>   camels to humans. Several known coronaviruses are circulating in
>   animals that have not yet infected humans.

It's not uncommon to have a virus be very widespread and infect humans via an animal host.  AIDS is also a virus which is believed to have spawned from animal to human contact.

Comment: Just to add some more detail: diseases that spread from animals to humans are known as Zoonotic diseases. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoonosis If memory serves, the disease moves from bats to a pig (do to de-habitation), to a person via the slaughtered pig. Since pigs can basically catch anything and people tend to keep them close, they're a pretty common vector for transmitting diseases. As of a few days ago, it still wasn't clear what the vector for the initial Coronavirus was https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00548-w